# How to regex all uri in a specific json key value

Tags: python, json, regex

I have been trying to be able to regex a special value: `"uri":` in a HTML that looks like:

```
test = {
      "enrichedEntity": {
        "type": "product",
        "id": "ern:product:uri:Clothes-air-1-sneakers-light-smoke-greygym-redwhiteblack-joc12o006-a21",
        "hints": [
          "gallery",
          "octopus:b14efd56-cfd9-4fb1-8383-0c37e99f2afb:kubernetes",
          "octopus:57a5852b-d16a-4021-8e8b-143bcdb9a815:Without gradient background",
          "octopus:46a18f4c-58e4-4fcc-94b5-ffdd14540983:WITHOUT_GRADIENT_BACKGROUND",
        ]
      },
      "graphqlCache": {
        "{\"id\":\"cb96571222c2df7160e55fd1765c7044a48026b6d47f61e99f9bdd6afffbe9f8\",\"variables\":{\"keys\":[\"barrythrill.prodpres.too.large.article\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.too.small.article\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.standard.article\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size_reco.message.recommended_size_shoe\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size_reco.message.recommended_size\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.review.cta.modal\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.sizereco\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.cta\",\"wardrobe.pdp.bought.notification\",\"wardrobe.pdp.returned.notification\",\"wardrobe.pdp.bought.size\",\"wardrobe.pdp.bought.link\"],\"host\":\"www.barrythrill.se\"}}": {
          "data": {
            "translations": {
              "barrythrill.prodpres.too.large.article": "Produkten är stor i storleken, så vårt tips är att ta en storlek mindre än vanligt.",
              "barrythrill.prodpres.too.small.article": "Produkten är liten i storleken, så vårt tips är att ta en storlek större än vanligt.",
              "barrythrill.prodpres.standard.article": "Vi rekommenderar vanlig storlek.",
              "barrythrill.prodpres.size_reco.message.recommended_size_shoe": "Wir empfehlen dir %3Cb>Größe {0}%3C/b>.",
              "barrythrill.prodpres.size_reco.message.recommended_size": "Vi rekommenderar %3Cb>storlek {0} %3C/b>.",
              "pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.review.cta.modal": "Varför?",
              "pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.sizereco": "Vill du få bättre",
              "pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.cta": "storleksrekommendationer?",
              "wardrobe.pdp.bought.notification": "Du köpte {0} {1}",
              "wardrobe.pdp.returned.notification": "Du returnerade denna produkt {0} {1}",
              "wardrobe.pdp.bought.size": "storlek {0}",
              "wardrobe.pdp.bought.link": "Se denna produkt i din garderob"
            }
          }
        },
        "{\"id\":\"cb96571222c2df7160e55fd1765c7044a48026b6d47f61e99f9bdd6afffbe9f8\",\"variables\":{\"keys\":[\"barrythrill.prodpres.delivery.long.distance.item\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.not_available\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.availability.equal.2or3\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.availability.equal1\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.selection.hint\",\"voucher.form.hl.step2\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.local\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.supplier\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.add_to_cart\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.request.title\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size_reminder.text\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.reminder.submit\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.reminder.success\",\"membership.pdp.sizereminder.eligible.link\",\"membership.pdp.sizereminder.eligible.text\",\"membership.pdp.sizereminder.active.text\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.no.fit.cta\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.out.of.stock.email.address\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.out.of.stock.notify.me.cta\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.out.of.stock.email.error\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.error\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.thank.you.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.thank.you.body\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.no.fit.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.no.fit.body\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.success.change.cta\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.out.of.stock.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.out.of.stock.body\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.body\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.submit\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.success.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.success.body\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.success.cta.add.to.bag\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.out.of.stock.message\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.headline\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.body\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.body2\",\"barrythrill.prodpres.size_reco.profile.link\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.modal.change.cta\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.size\",\"pdp.dialog.tile.sizing.brand\",\"catalog.article.brand\",\"mobile.app.filter.search.brand.placeholderText\"],\"host\":\"www.barrythrill.se\"}}": {
        },
        "{\"id\":\"cb96571222c2df7160e55fd1765c7044a48026b6d47f61e99f9bdd6afffbe9f8\",\"variables\":{\"keys\":[\"max.order.limit.notification.pdp\",\"max.customer.limit.notification.pdp\"],\"host\":\"www.barrythrill.se\"}}": {
          "data": {
            "translations": {
              "max.order.limit.notification.pdp": "Es sieht so aus, als hätten Sie bereits die maximale Anzahl exklusiver Artikel gekauft.",
              "max.customer.limit.notification.pdp": "Sie haben dieses Produkt bereits gekauft und als Kunde die Höchstgrenze erreicht."
            }
          }
      
        },
        "{\"id\":\"6d02003e11d0bb4d2aa57493c0453715a0e1a20ca8c5ae3e853c57eaaa99621b\",\"variables\":{\"id\":\"ern:product:uri:Clothes-air-1-sneakers-light-smoke-greygym-redwhiteblack-joc12o006-a21\"}}": {
          "data": {
            "product": {
              "id": "ern:product::JOC12O006-A21",
              "comingSoon": true,
              "condition": null,
              "simplesWithStock": [
                {
                  "sku": "JOC12O006-A210070000"
                }
              ],
              "relevantEntities": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "id": "ern:collection:res:res-reco-products-similar-to-product:_CnULuWVdQq_ynK8PrPQKFN36VqPrkkTiUJGG-zK0FqFzxG1MSggeDNrdK86DA9m.cQJUL5yP5OqWN4tvHgLJlia0redeTqgkT9tuP50i6DPHuyyMwQSJv2Y1VQDQkGqpEA60sOVfeDiVh5_att-9M8_rsMVlko7FgSlG9b_WKCwGVhhk2nvI7ynYVRGu4ocDABzjUVvz-EGWxc8ujmNpis_nJQS4mLqG1_DfWbMHUA7JHAc5zxeyXR9_gF9GzBOdIcXeGK59Ta-1WuSCXHKYBxxkq-2QE5iP7IfTUg7XACOonSBWwMfFtvx6AFYVwq7Z0ZqCc1r8o8J7DGiArW-Wv58T-KiOY4VOGto1F38kzGTGaCDfcFkA0AiQmM52gQDeEbww94i3IZI.v2",
                      "reason": {
                        "kind": "SIMILAR"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "id": "ern:collection:res:res-reco-products-with-same-tag-as-product:_CnULuWVdQq_ynK8PrPQKFN36VqPrkkTiUJGG-zK0FqFzxG1MSggeDNrdK86DA9m.cQJUL5yP5OqWN4tvHgLJlia0redeTqgkT9tuP50i6DPHuyyMwQSJv2Y1VQDQkGqpEA60sOVfeDiVh5_att-9M8_rsMVlko7FgSlG9b_WKCwGVhhk2nvI7ynYVRGu4ocDABzjUVvz-EGWxc8ujmNpis_nJQS4mLqG1_DfWbMHUA7JHAc5zxeyXR9_gF9GzBOdIcXeGK59Ta-1WuSCXHKYBxxkq-2QE5iP7IfTUg7XACOonSBWwMfFtvx6AFYVwq7Z0ZqCc1r8o8J7DGiArW-Wv58T-KiOY4VOGto1F38kzGTGaCDfcFkA0AiQmM52gQDeEbww94i3IZI.v2",
                      "reason": {
                        "kind": "SAME_TAG"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "id": "ern:collection:res:res-reco-products-sponsored:_CnULuWVdQq_ynK8PrPQKFN36VqPrkkTiUJGG-zK0FqFzxG1MSggeDNrdK86DA9m.cQJUL5yP5OqWN4tvHgLJlia0redeTqgkT9tuP50i6DPHuyyMwQSJv2Y1VQDQkGqpEA60sOVfeDiVh5_att-9M8_rsMVlko7FgSlG9b_WKCwGVhhk2nvI7ynYVRGu4ocDABzjUVvz-EGWxc8ujmNpis_nJQS4mLqG1_DfWbMHUA7JHAc5zxeyXR9_gF9GzBOdIcXeGK59Ta-1WuSCXHKYBxxkq-2QE5iP7IfTUg7XACOonSBWwMfFtvx6AFYVwq7Z0ZqCc1r8o8J7DGiArW-Wv58T-KiOY4VOGto1F38kzGTGaCDfcFkA0AiQmM52gQDeEbww94i3IZI.v2",
                      "reason": {
                        
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "id": "ern:collection:res:res-reco-products-xsell-to-product:_CnULuWVdQq_ynK8PrPQKFN36VqPrkkTiUJGG-zK0FqFzxG1MSggeDNrdK86DA9m.cQJUL5yP5OqWN4tvHgLJlia0redeTqgkT9tuP50i6DPHuyyMwQSJv2Y1VQDQkGqpEA60sOVfeDiVh5_att-9M8_rsMVlko7FgSlG9b_WKCwGVhhk2nvI7ynYVRGu4ocDABzjUVvz-EGWxc8ujmNpis_nJQS4mLqG1_DfWbMHUA7JHAc5zxeyXR9_gF9GzBOdIcXeGK59Ta-1WuSCXHKYBxxkq-2QE5iP7IfTUg7XACOonSBWwMfFtvx6AFYVwq7Z0ZqCc1r8o8J7DGiArW-Wv58T-KiOY4VOGto1F38kzGTGaCDfcFkA0AiQmM52gQDeEbww94i3IZI.v2",
                      "reason": {
                        "kind": "CROSS_SELL"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "{\"id\":\"86e6491a72545f4c91d7dc380d5c3f40ee094fdd5037845410f24de0ddd3dcf3\",\"variables\":{\"id\":\"ern:product:uri:Clothes-air-1-sneakers-light-smoke-greygym-redwhiteblack-joc12o006-a21\"}}": {
          "data": {
            "product": {
              "id": "ern:product::JOC12O006-A21",
              "displayPrice": {
                "original": {
                  "formatted": "1 095,00 kr"
                },
                "promotional": null
              },
              "brand": {
                "name": "Clothes"
              },
              "color": {
                "name": "light smoke grey/gym red/white/black",
                "label": "vit"
              },
              "urisInAllLocales": [
                {
                  "locale": "fi-FI",
                  "uri": "/Clothes-air-1-matalavartiset-tennarit-light-smoke-greygym-redwhiteblack-joc12o006-a21.html"
                }
              ],
              "name": "AIR 1 - Sneakers - light smoke grey/gym red/white/black",
              "category": "Sneakers",
              "sku": "JOC12O006-A21",
              "primaryImage": {
                "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/0034959e2d1a3105aa6c338b9cea6ffd/28bcaf048f714eb8b66d715a43848c6b.jpg?imwidth=103&filter=packshot"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "{\"id\":\"c34970edbf9399da7d80f7007b06df1ba5039e994b73558c50f864707704e828\",\"variables\":{\"id\":\"ern:product:uri:Clothes-air-1-sneakers-light-smoke-greygym-redwhiteblack-joc12o006-a21\"}}": {
          "data": {
            "product": {
              "id": "ern:product::JOC12O006-A21",
              "name": "AIR 1 - Sneakers - light smoke grey/gym red/white/black",
              "sku": "JOC12O006-A21",
              "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-light-smoke-greygym-redwhiteblack-joc12o006-a21.html",
              "comingSoon": true,
              "brand": {
                "name": "Clothes",
                "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes/"
              },
              "family": {
                "products": {
                  "edges": [
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "sku": "JOC12O006-A15",
                        "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-a15.html",
                        "color": {
                          "name": "white"
                        },
                        "beautyColorThumbnail": null,
                        "standardColorThumbnail": {
                          "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/ff8266dcd8363db590f8cfd2e85a6b0a/cf0dc2ddd3884a78835d4ce8f972b56f.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                        },
                        "fallbackStandardColorThumbnails": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/ff8266dcd8363db590f8cfd2e85a6b0a/cf0dc2ddd3884a78835d4ce8f972b56f.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ],
                        "galleryMedia": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/ff8266dcd8363db590f8cfd2e85a6b0a/cf0dc2ddd3884a78835d4ce8f972b56f.jpg?imwidth=762&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "sku": "JOC12O006-Q14",
                        "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-q14.html",
                        "color": {
                          "name": "gym red/black/white"
                        },
                        "beautyColorThumbnail": null,
                        "standardColorThumbnail": {
                          "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/2e4ae62f312b3cbc9f2892b71c233cfe/adb2bac4283e49dd8297955d4816fa14.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                        },
                        "fallbackStandardColorThumbnails": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/2e4ae62f312b3cbc9f2892b71c233cfe/adb2bac4283e49dd8297955d4816fa14.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ],
                        "galleryMedia": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/2e4ae62f312b3cbc9f2892b71c233cfe/adb2bac4283e49dd8297955d4816fa14.jpg?imwidth=762&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "sku": "JOC12O006-A13",
                        "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-a13.html",
                        "color": {
                          "name": "white/hyper crimson/light bone/vintage lichen"
                        },
                        "beautyColorThumbnail": null,
                        "standardColorThumbnail": {
                          "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/9e3d10b1e7973ce297f8d7064ba68daf/97bef05fea1442f99933d0b968d048ef.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                        },
                        "fallbackStandardColorThumbnails": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/9e3d10b1e7973ce297f8d7064ba68daf/97bef05fea1442f99933d0b968d048ef.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ],
                        "galleryMedia": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/9e3d10b1e7973ce297f8d7064ba68daf/97bef05fea1442f99933d0b968d048ef.jpg?imwidth=762&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "sku": "JOC12O006-A12",
                        "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-a12.html",
                        "color": {
                          "name": "white/pure platinum"
                        },
                        "beautyColorThumbnail": null,
                        "standardColorThumbnail": {
                          "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/ce31897aec983e1a9f9d3e1b1ff4f30b/c445180f638d44b18c9b40db8331a18f.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                        },
                        "fallbackStandardColorThumbnails": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/ce31897aec983e1a9f9d3e1b1ff4f30b/c445180f638d44b18c9b40db8331a18f.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ],
                        "galleryMedia": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/ce31897aec983e1a9f9d3e1b1ff4f30b/c445180f638d44b18c9b40db8331a18f.jpg?imwidth=762&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "sku": "JOC12O006-C11",
                        "uri": "https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-c11.html",
                        "color": {
                          "name": "black/light smoke grey/white"
                        },
                        "beautyColorThumbnail": null,
                        "standardColorThumbnail": {
                          "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/dea0b4c2d96c3bb1ad82d69ce8388440/ec826d3cccf24b74ac20d42a20dc6d69.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                        },
                        "fallbackStandardColorThumbnails": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/dea0b4c2d96c3bb1ad82d69ce8388440/ec826d3cccf24b74ac20d42a20dc6d69.jpg?imwidth=156&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ],
                        "galleryMedia": [
                          {
                            "uri": "https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/dea0b4c2d96c3bb1ad82d69ce8388440/ec826d3cccf24b74ac20d42a20dc6d69.jpg?imwidth=762&filter=packshot"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "inWishlist": false,
              "sizeAdvice": null,
              "benefits": [
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

I have shortened the code quite a lot to be able to show you guys the code.  I removed the HTML which contains this JSON snippet.

What I have done right now is following:

```
test = re.findall(
           r'(?<="uri":)"(https:\/\/www.barrythrill[^"]+.html)"',
           test,
           re.M | re.S
          )
```

The problem with the code is that it will scrape all that contains `www.barrythrill.se/*` and I do just want to scrape all `uri` elements in the:

```
"family": {
    "products": {
      "edges": [
```

Output:

It should only print out these links since that's the only links that are inside the `"family": { "products": { "edges": [`

```
[https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-a15.html,
https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-q14.html,
https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-a13.html,
https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-a12.html,
https://www.barrythrill.se/Clothes-air-1-sneakers-joc12o006-c11.html]
```

My question is, how can I scrape only the uri's inside the hierarchy I mentioned above?

Comment: Is using the json data as json not an option for you?

Comment: @Chillie Not really due to it contains a randomized key ID which I can't be able to do through `.json()` :(

Comment: Why is that a problem? Just traverse all the `"id"` keys until you find the ones which contain this hierarchy of keys.

Comment: @Alireza Actually probably the problem is that the supposed HTML input has several formatting errors, probably due to bad copy/paste.

Comment: @tripleee That could be an option I guess, I thought it would be easier to through regex but indeed I could be wrong aswell :)